# Delete entry from macports 'select' list

Tags: macos, macports

I have installed and uninstalled many ports from [MacPorts](https://www.macports.org/). This includes several ports which are available in different versions and can be selected using the `port select` utility:

```
Name        Selected      Options
====        ========      =======
awscli      py38-awscli2  none
black       none          black310 none
gcc         none          mp-gcc11 none
pip         pip39         pip3-apple pip310 pip38 pip39 none
pip2        none          none
pip3        pip39         pip3-apple pip310 pip38 pip39 none
postgresql  postgresql13  postgresql12 postgresql13 none
python      python39      python310 python38 python39 none
python3     python39      python310 python38 python39 none
virtualenv  virtualenv39  virtualenv310 virtualenv38 virtualenv39 none
```

I am no longer using several of these, and have uninstalled the ports, and `${portname}_select` packages. However, these entries still show up in the list, even though no packages are available for selection.

How can I clean up the list of available software so that it's consistent with what is currently installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that this list is generated from the filesystem. The path `/opt/local/etc/select/` contains directories for all of the 'selectable' software. I removed the directories for the unused software and now the list is clean.